# Can a RDP file be harmful?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a RDP file which I need to execute on Windows 7.  The file was given to me by an organization.
It allows (~should allow) me an access to use a software in another network.

Is it possible for a RDP file to contain malicious code?

Most of the file's fields are clear, except for the signature field which is encoded (don't know the encoding).
It *looks* similar to this (but much longer):

```
signature:s:ENBIFvZh6NLQmMDAwNTM ...(much more here)
```

Please notice that I'm asking whether a RDP file, **potentially**, may contain malicious code?
For example, it doesn't matter which file I try to load into the program "Notepad++" or "gedit", it will always consider that file as a text file, ergo potentially no problems should occur.

Comment: Should be fine. Did you not create the file yourself? If you really want to be sure, you can right click on the file and choose edit with notepad, grab the IP/hostname and the username (if attached) and just enter it yourself into the RDP session window. If for some reason you don't want that shortcut to execute the mstsc.exe

Comment: @Narzard: I did not create the file myself - it was given to me.

Comment: execute it on a test system that has good av installed. Or upload the file to ...https://www.virustotal.com/

Comment: @Moab: But does a RDP file, **potentially**, may contain malicious code?

Comment: Nazard nailed it. Just enter the user name and password manually.1 Start 2 run 3 mstsc.. The file is for people that can't figure out where mstsc is... For that matter grab a copy of 2x and log in, or any RDP client.

Comment: Everything is impossible until it isn't, yes its possible, but has it been done, who knows.